# How to create a dataset of ids that get treated at some point in time? (R)

Tags: r

I have a longitudinal dataset with 3 important variables: ID, Year, Treatment

I would like to keep all the IDs that get treated at some point of time and drop all the IDs that never get treated. How do I do this on R?

Example:

| ID | Year | Treatment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 2000 | 0 |
| 0001 | 2001 | 0 |
| 0001 | 2002 | 0 |
| 0002 | 2000 | 0 |
| 0002 | 2001 | 0 |
| 0002 | 2002 | 1 |

I would like to keep all observations of ID 0002 (Treated at some point in time), but drop all of ID 0001 (Never treated). I have a very big dataset with more IDs than that so I can not do this manually.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the IDs that have treatment, then subset those IDs:

```
d[ d$ID %in% unique(d[ d$Treatment == 1,  "ID" ]), ]
#     ID Year Treatment
# 4 0002 2000         0
# 5 0002 2001         0
# 6 0002 2002         1
```

Comment: Great, this works. Thank you for the good and fast reply :)

Comment: @EliasW You are welcome. Accept as answer if it worked, also check the other alternative in the linked posts.